# Mapproxy docker image mapproxy:2.0.2-dev fails at startup

Tags: mapproxy

I have tried to launch official MapProxy docker image
ghcr.io/mapproxy/mapproxy/mapproxy:2.0.2-dev
but it didn't worked with the following reason (from logs):

```
Found libproj >=5. Using this library without pyproj is deprecated and not fully supported. Please install pyproj >= 2
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problems (old and new) I have built a new image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ghcr.io/mapproxy/mapproxy/mapproxy:2.0.2-dev
RUN pip3 install pyproj boto3
```

The new image works fine.